# how to hide navigation menu list?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

i am doing website which i have drop down list like following image[image]

it works fine, but  while my browser size decreasing that menu will fall down like following image[image]

here is my css code:

```
  nav ul ul {
display: none;
        }
  nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
background: #efefef; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding: 0 20px;
border-radius: 10px;  
list-style: none;
position: fixed;
display: inline-table;
overflow:hidden;
   }
  nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;

}
nav ul li {
float: left;

    }
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}
    nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
    }

 nav ul li a {
display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;
   }
```

and here is my html code:

```
![enter image description here][3]
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly if I think that what you're trying to achieve is a layout where select menu items are hidden depending on maximum viewport width?

Comment: how should i get rid of that? Is any property to set? @Maritim

Comment: The way to go is responsive CSS and media queries.

Comment: If you're just wanting it not to stack, set a fixed width on the parent menu element. If you want it to be responsive you need to add different styles for different screen widths. So in the answer saying use responsive CSS you would readd your menu CSS there and adjust the sizes to fit on that particular screen width in the media query. PS. Fix your HTML I am pretty sure that isn't your menu HTML you have there.

Comment: Your users won't thank you for taking away navigational elements just because they have a narrower screen than you would like them to have.  How do you expect them to view "Tutorials" if the link is hidden?  It would be better if you used media queries to detect device widths and presented an attractive vertical menu for narrower displays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS media queries to hide the menu when the screen resolution gets smaller. Add this to your CSS code:

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {

nav {
    display:none;
}

}
```

For mobile users, add this line to your `<head>` segment too:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: i have tried with your code when the screedn resolution gets smaller whole menu will disappear. i want show remain also...

Comment: Then I suggest you make smaller paddings and fonts for when the screen width becomes smaller, there's a lot of space around the text on your buttons. Just add the new values to the @media{...} segment like I did with nav{...} in my example.